# Set-Cookie header in Response was discarded by Browser(Cookie)

Tags: java, http, web

I want to set cookie from server-side(java) to browse, but it do NOT work.
Then I take further test to send several different http headers to browser;

```
     resp.addHeader("Authorization", "dptestdptest");
     resp.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "access_token=ODczYWMxYTNlM2ZkNTYxNWEwYmMzZWRlMGExODkxNTc=; Domain=192.168.11.104; Path=/;");
     resp.addHeader("Set-Cookiehello", "access_token=ODczYWMxYTNlM2ZkNTYxNWEwYmMzZWRlMGExODkxNTc=; Domain=192.168.11.104; Path=/;");
```

Check network tag in chrome, the result as following;
Seems ONLY "Set-Cookie" was discarded; Others can be accepted by browser; It make me confused;
P.S. under CORS environment;

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.11.104
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie
Authorization: dptestdptest
Content-Length: 57
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 10 May 2020 16:33:33 GMT
Set-Cookiehello: access_token=ODczYWMxYTNlM2ZkNTYxNWEwYmMzZWRlMGExODkxNTc=; Domain=192.168.11.104;Path=/;
```

Comment: Can you check Applications>Cookie in chrome developer tools if cookie is there.

Comment: Chrome version is v74; while i use Friefox(v58) to further test; I found i can see "Set-Cookie" header in FireFox console; but cannot find content in cookie;

Comment: I cannot find the content in cookie; Actually, As I cannot find content in cookie, then i further check Response Header, and  find "Set-Cookie" header is missing;